# Update com Resource AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sql-update, resources, callback

Existe o método `Callback` para o `resource.update` no `AngularJS`?

Tipo,

```
var instancia = Resource.get({id:1}, function(data){
    instancia.$update({id:idModelo}, modeloAtualizado)
});
```

Isso funciona, o registro é atualizado perfeitamente, porém, eu gostaria de tratar se a atualização ocorreu com sucesso ou se houve falha.

Nos demais métodos, `$post`, `$create` etc existe o método Callback, porém, no `$update` não funciona.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Minha factory resource:

```
app.factory( "meuResource", function ($resource) {
    return $resource(URL+"meuModelo/:id", null, {
        'update' : { method: "PUT"}, 
        'get' : { method: "GET"},
        'post': { method: 'POST'},
        'delete' : { method: 'DELETE'}        
    });
});
```

Meu método de atualização:

```
$scope.edit = function(){
    Resource.get({id:$scope.vm.id}, function(data){
        try{ 
            var instancia = angular.copy($scope.vm);      

            Resource.update({id:instancia.id}, instancia);
        }
        catch(e){
            toastr.error("Não foi possível atualizar o registro!");
        }
    }, function(data){
        toastr.error("Ocorreu uma falha na gravação do registro!", {timeOut:2500});                
        console.log(data);
    });       
}
```

Existe um `try` dentro do "`get`", porém, a exceção só será lançada se houver um erro na dentro do "`get`" durante a execução.

Como o "`Resource.update({id:instancia.id}, instancia);`" é assíncrono, se ocorrer um erro na sua execução, esse erro passa despercebido.

Answer (score 0):

Então, depois de conversar com meu amigo Sávio Freitas, o mesmo me mostrou uma luz.. dito e feito, funcionou.

```
            Resource.update({id:instancia.id}, instancia, function(data){
                //callback de successo
            }, function(data){
                //callback de error
            });
```

Obrigado!